# Manual Price quote web service sample request and response

Tags: sabre

I tried to implement the Price Quote webservice. Its working fine but unable to override the base bare amount. This service automatically created the price quote based on the sabre fare. But i need to manually set the base bare and taxes. How can i achieve this using sabre web service? Please provide sample requests and responses if you have..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OTA_AirPriceRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.11.0">
<PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
  <OptionalQualifiers>
     <PricingQualifiers>
        <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
     </PricingQualifiers>
  </OptionalQualifiers>
</PriceRequestInformation>
</OTA_AirPriceRQ>
```

Comment: Can you give some more informations and show some code? It´s impossible to answer your question like this.

Comment: Hi Kabaehr, I am trying to call the  AirPriceLLSRQ webservice.  Please find the sample request which i used below..
<OTA_AirPriceRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.11.0">
   <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
      <OptionalQualifiers>
         <PricingQualifiers>
            <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
         </PricingQualifiers>
      </OptionalQualifiers>
   </PriceRequestInformation>
</OTA_AirPriceRQ>

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of posting a comment. This is hard readable

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific discount to apply to the public fare, based on specific fare basis code you can use: OTA_AirPriceRQ/PriceRequestInformation/OptionalQualifiers/PricingQualifiers/CommandPricing

Otherwise if you need further flexibility for pricing you can use phase IV ticket record pricing:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/fulfill/create_phaseiv_ticket_record

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help..  i need to override the base fare totally and i dont want to apply any discount... And the PhaseIV ticket record service is not applicable to use for airlines.. that service only for Travel agents..

Answer (score 0):

I used SabreCommandRQ to accomplish this task, starting with this command **WTKT1 and then playing with the response in the background as if I was using Sabre Red's blue screen (to send mask values, the cData property must be set to "true").

Recently, Sabre released [this web service](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/fulfill/create_manual_price_quote_ticket_record) ManualPriceQuoteAddInfoLLSRQ, to make things easier :)